# Math for 2d movement with max speed?

Tags: 2d, movement

I need some help with math in a 2d environment. I have a joystick that controls the acceleration vetor for the player figure.

Its suppose to look like the ground is slippery which makes the figure turn slowly and accelerate and decelerate slowly.

Now, I can do this without any problem if I remove the maximum speed, but Im having problem when using a speed cap.

This is my calculation:

```
func move() {
    if acceleration == CGPointZero && currentSpeed != 0 {
        direction *= 0.95
    }
    else {
        if self.currentSpeed > maxSpeed {
            // This is almost working, just a little buggy, please help here with quality mathamatics :)

            let angle = CGPointZero.angleToPoint(direction) // In Radians
            direction = CGPoint(cos(angle), sin(angle)) * maxSpeed
        }
        else {
            direction += acceleration
        }
    }

    self.center += direction
}
```

move() is getting called by a timer running at 32 fps. acceleration is a Vector pointing to the direction the user wants his figure to go. currentSpeed is calculated using [Pythagorean theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem). direction is acceleration * speed. maxSpeed is a number. self.center is the centerpoint of the figure.

Comment: What actually happens with the current code? Hard to look for a problem without knowing the problem.

Comment: When steering while moving at max speed it isnt smooth, its like the calculation lost some decimals.

Comment: And sometimes it doesnt steer at all.

Comment: Have you tried debugging the code on your own? Set a breakpoint and see what happens. At which point does it deviate from your expectations? (Also, what programming language is this?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any real problems with your implementation here, but I suspect your problem is buried in `angleToPoint()`. I couldn't find any mention of it in the `CGPoint` documentation, so I assume it's something you've implemented yourself. Make sure you're using `atan2()` or equivalent, not just `atan()`.

However, it'd be easier not to use any trigonometry at all:

```
if self.currentSpeed > maxSpeed {
    direction *= maxSpeed/direction.magnitude();
}
```

This scales `direction` down to `maxSpeed` while keeping the direction of the vector the same.

---

I'd suggest renaming `direction` to `velocity` - not only is that what it is called canonically, but also `direction` doesn't just contain the direction of movement, it's also got the magnitude of that movement.

Comment: Thanks! I did like this: `direction *= maxSpeed/currentSpeed` And yes, calling it velocity seems like a better name, thanks for some standards too x)